# Rainfall Statistics

Tags: c++

I have an assignment in class to gather the rainfall for twelve months and display them in order of highest to lowest.  I can get the numeric values to display but not the months to display.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std:

int rainfall(int [], string [], int);
void sortArray(int [], string [], int);

int main()
{
    //Program info
    cout <<"Enter rainfall for each month and the progran will display the rainfall," <<endl;
    cout <<"sorted in order of rainfall, from highest to lowest.\n" <<endl;

    int const MONTHS = 12;
    int values[MONTHS];
    string name[MONTHS] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    rainfall(values, name, MONTHS);
    sortArray(values, name, MONTHS);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

int rainfall(int values[], string name[], int MONTHS)
{
    //Gather rainfall number from user
    cout << "\nPlease enter the amount of rainfall for each month.\n " << endl;
    for(int month = 0; month <= MONTHS -1; month++)
    {
        cout << name[month] << ": ";
        cin >> values[month];

        //Validation to ensure a negative number is not entered 
        if(values[month] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Negative rainfall is not possible. Re-enter number." << endl;
            cin >> values[month];
        }
    }
    return values[MONTHS];
}

void sortArray(int values[], string name[], int MONTHS)
{
    int temp;
    bool swap;
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count = 0; count < MONTHS - 1; count++)
        {
            if(values[count] < values[count + 1])
            {
                temp = values[count];
                values[count] = values[count + 1];
                values[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swap);

    cout << "\nHere are the months sorted from highest to lowest:\n";

    for (int index = 0; index  < MONTHS; index++)
        cout << values[index] << " ";
}
```

Comment: When you post a question in stack overflow, try to make it more clear. For example, what is the expected output? What is the actual output? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 3):

Two things I see:

1. You're likely going to need to swap the months value in order for it to appear as you desire.
2. To get the months to print out:

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index  < MONTHS; index++)
       cout << values[index] << " " << name[index] << endl;
   ```

   I added `endl`, cause I think you'll like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're sorting the rainfall values directly, which means that you're losing the information about which value corresponds to each month. A good way to solve it would be to pass an array of indices and sort that array. In other words, instead of

```
void sortArray(int values[], string name[], int MONTHS)
```

you would have

```
void sortArray(int indices[], int values[], string name[], int MONTHS)
```

The idea is to initialize the `indices` array from 0 to 11 in the `main` function:

```
int indices[MONTHS];
for (int month = 0; month < MONTHS; month++)
{
    indices[MONTHS] = month;
}
```

Of course, when sorting the `indices` array, you would need to compare the actual values those indices point to, so instead of

```
if(values[count] < values[count + 1])
{
    temp = values[count];
    values[count] = values[count + 1];
    values[count + 1] = temp;
    swap = true;
}
```

you would have

```
if(values[indices[count]] < values[indices[count + 1]])
{
    temp = indices[count];
    indices[count] = indices[count + 1];
    indices[count + 1] = temp;
    swap = true;
}
```

Just in case it's not clear, here's an explanation of what we're doing and why we're doing it. Instead of sorting the list of rainfall *values*, you're sorting the list of *months* and accessing the values (and the month names) indirectly through that list. In other words, you're saying: "I've got the values for January, February, ..., December, now sort them" and once you're done sorting, the result is something like "Okay, the months in correct order, from lowest rainfall to highest, are February, May, December, June, ..., August".

So, how do you print out the results?

```
for (int index = 0; index < MONTHS; index++)
{
    cout << "Rainfall for " << name[indices[index]] << " was " << values[indices[index]] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your biggest troubles are coming from your Data Structure design. A good data structure will make algorithms much simpler to implement.

Here is an example of a struct that is designed to encapsulate all the data you are tracking in one location:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Structs are useful for combining related data.
struct Month
{
    enum
    {
        JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL,
        AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC, NUM_MONTHS
    };

    const char *name;
    int rainfall;

    Month(const char *name)
    {
        this->name = name;
        rainfall = 0;
    }

    bool operator<(const struct Month& other) const
    {
        return (rainfall < other.rainfall);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Static struct initialization avoids the hassle of working with pointers.
    struct Month months[Month::NUM_MONTHS] =
    {
        Month("Jan"),
        Month("Feb"),
        Month("Mar"),
        Month("Apr"),
        Month("May"),
        Month("Jun"),
        Month("Jul"),
        Month("Aug"),
        Month("Sep"),
        Month("Oct"),
        Month("Nov"),
        Month("Dec")
    };

    // Enums can be used for clearer access before sorting array.
    months[Month::JAN].rainfall = 7;
    months[Month::FEB].rainfall = 2;
    months[Month::MAR].rainfall = 5;
    months[Month::APR].rainfall = 3;

    // Months can be easily swapped in the array.
    // Be cautious that this does break the Enum associations.
    struct Month tmp = months[0];
    months[0] = months[1];
    months[1] = tmp;

    // If you can use the STL, sorting is extremely easy.
    vector<struct Month> months_v(months, months + Month::NUM_MONTHS);
    sort(months_v.begin(), months_v.end());

    vector<struct Month>::iterator it;
    for (it = months_v.begin(); it != months_v.end(); it++)
        printf("%s\t%d\n", it->name, it->rainfall);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is `C++` you might want to replace `const char *` and `printf` by something more appropriate.